# C# excel - extract only rows within a range of columns

Tags: c#, excel, range

I have the following code:

```
Excel.Range range = workSheet.UsedRange;
for (rowCount = 2; rowCount <= range.Rows.Count; rowCount++)
  {
     //Do something here
  }
```

However, I encounter the following problem. If I have the following excel data:

```
cell1, cell2, cell3

cell4, cell5, cell6

..............cell7
```

range.Rows.Count will return 3. However, I don't care about column C - it has some data that is used for drop-down lists within say column 1. How can I get the range.Rows.Count only for columns A and B?

For example:
[image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot and be clear about what you want to count and what you want to ignore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there are no blanks in column A, just walk down rows until you hit a blank row using `range.Offset(x,y)`: (sorry, I'm more fluent with Excel VBA, you'll have to translate to C#)

```
Dim myCell as Range
set myCell = workSheet.Range("A2");
Do Until myCell.Formula = ""
     'Do something here
     set myCell = myCell.Offset(1,0) 'Moves down a row 
Loop
```

Or just loop through numerically using `Worksheet.Cells(row,col)`:

```
Dim myRow as Integer
myRow = 2
Do Until cells(myrow,2).Formula = ""
     'Do something here
     myRow = myRow + 1
Loop
```

**Edit**: You could also use `Range("A1").End(xlDown)` to find the last populated cell of the first column. This should work with your current logic. Something like (I'll try it in C#):

```
Excel.Range range = workSheet.Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown));
for (rowCount = 2; rowCount <= range.Rows.Count; rowCount++)
  {
     //Do something here
  }
```